# Crawl over stuff

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have game where the enemies head straight for the player.

However, if there is an obstacle in the way, i want the enemies to simply crawl over it following its surface without changing direction. Sort of how a thick gel would flow over something.

So basically the enemies vertical angle and its height in space would change to crawl over any obstacle without changing its direction.

I guess I would have to detect when the enemy hit an obstacle, then determine the angle of the surface that was hit, then somehow adjust the angle and stick to the sides of that obstacle to crawl over it somehow.

Anybody knows of an existing script that does it, or how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at the `NavMesh` components. It might help what you are looking for, as you can get an `Gameobject` to follow a set path/area, even over obstacles.

There is some Unity documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) and there are plenty of tutorials online! :)